# @JsonSerialize not converting my date format from controller springboot 2.2.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime-format

i have model (ModelX) with date

```
@Entity
class ModelX
   ....
    @JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
    private Long date;
```

Date Serializer

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime>
{

private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

@Override
public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, 
                      SerializerProvider arg2)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    gen.writeString(formatter.print(value));
}
}
```

my controller

```
@RestController
public class XC {

 @GetMapping(value = "/get/{main_key}"
 public get ModelX get(@PathVariable("main_key") String main_key) {
   return repository.get(main_key);
 }
```

}

the fetch works but my date is a Long but i want a date "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: I don't think it will call your serialize method because the type of your date is Long and the serialize method is expecting a DateTime

Comment: SOLVED: I fixed it by using ObjectMapper instead of Gson as my default deserializer

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON custom serializer you can format the LONG date

```
@Entity
class ModelX
   ....
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateCustom.class)
    private Long date;
```

Custom Serializer

```
@Component
public class JsonDateCustom extends JsonSerializer<Long> {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Long value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(value);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);

    }
}
```